# How to open a new form on top of the current one when clicking the button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, onclick, lightning-button

I have a "new" button in my aura component (lightning: button). When I click on this button, I want to open a new form ("New Contact") on top of the current form, in which I need to fill in the fields to add a new contact. "New contact" is a separate component of the aura.
How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a modal pop up check these [link1](https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce/) [link2](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/)

Comment: Thank! This is what I needed!